# Error happen when use pip to install modules for pypy

Tags: python, pip

I just soft linked the pip in `/usr/bin` to `opt/pypy/bin`, where I installed the pypy version of pip.

Initially it worked well, and I downloaded Django, pil and some other common libraries, but after installing wxpython it started to throw out an error.

It seems the pip related modules are cursed but I am not quite sure, and I really don't know what to do next.

Here is the error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/pypy -u -c 
"import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3ld6pS/lxml/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',open) (__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-lK69XJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3ld6pS/lxml
```

Comment: i had this issue yesterday with some packages i was installing, updating setuptools using pip seemed to fix it, at least for the packages i wanted

Comment: @JamesKent I tried to update and now it partially fixed. for some packages like numpy still dose not work but i have got what i need. thank you for the information

Comment: what is the error that numpy gives? can you post a traceback?

Comment: @JamesKent exactly same, but it sopted for a while before the previous one raised.Here is where it stoped:   `Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy ... -^error
  Failed building wheel for numpy
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
Failed to build numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
`

Comment: you could try updating distutils and see if that helps